# Is there a way to embed parts of a SharePoint site into an iframe?

Tags: html, iframe, sharepoint

I need to embed a version history of files on a SharePoint server into another local html file. When I try to do this, the server tells me that SharePoint denied access. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: depends if your share point site allows iframes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options.  Most companies will have to lock down their sites not to allow them due to security audits

Comment: Well, no it doesn't. The company will also not change this, so I guess there is no way. Is there maybe another way that doesn't use iFrames?

Comment: write an api that you could consume?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! I am not experienced enough to write an API, I think.